# Running excel line graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a set of data points in a spreadsheet with another set of line graphs plotting that data over time.  New data in entered every month and each month I have to manually update the charts to display the new data.

I would like a solution to get the chart to automatically pick up the new data once entered.

I know this can be done because for some (minority) of my sheets, this happens automatically so long as my input range extends to columns beyond what has been populated.
However when I try to do this in other charts, this skews the graph such that the section to the right is empty/blank (as the values have not yet been entered)

I have tried to assess the differences in the graphs (both line charts, data entered is the same format etc) but have not been able to identify any differences.

[Data is entered for a number of parameters over time. Time is plotted in columns from left to right and can not easily be changed due to the number of other data series in the range.
Speadsheets are created in Excel 1997-2003 and 2007 though I cannot associate a link to updating charts to either version]

Answer (score 0):

The difference probably isn't in the graphs, but in the raw data.

Convert your row data to tables (insert tab - table), then select again the source data of the charts, so instead of cell references (e.g. `A1:E50`) you'll see the name of the table (e.g. `Table1`).

This way whenever you enter new data your chart will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thank you.  I seem to be able to work that.  The table un-helpfully inserts a row above the new 'Table' in each case which puts my spreadsheet out of order.  Is there any way to avoid this? If I un-check the 'Header Row' box, the header disappears but the rows remain one row down.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do a table without header row.